# Delete record from array if values matches

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I have an array:

```
[
{"sku":"5221","qty":1,"price":17.5,"desc":"5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"},
{"sku":"11004","qty":1,"price":30.95,"desc":"150 - Q-Plus 16oz"}}
```

Now I want to delete the first row by matching sku, something like if sku == 5221 than delete whole record row:

```
{"sku":"5221","qty":1,"price":17.5,"desc":"5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: By the time you're doing this, you're not dealing with JSON, just an array. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: convert JSON string into a PHP data type (array/object) using `json_decode()` Then process the PHP Array of objects just like any other

Comment: Generally, read the JSON into an array, then manipulate the array as needed (adding, removing, modifying rows/cells). Just write the array back to a json file when you are done manipulating it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the JSON STRING into a PHP data type using `json_decode()` In this case the data type will be an array of objects as json is wrapped in `[]` and objects are denoted by `{}`

Then process the resulting array looking for the Key you want to delete and `UNSET` that array occurance.

```
<?php
$json_string =
'[
{"sku":"5221","qty":1,"price":17.5,"desc":"5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"},
{"sku":"11004","qty":1,"price":30.95,"desc":"150 - Q-Plus 16oz"}
]';

$array = json_decode($json_string);

echo 'before'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $key => &$obj) {
    if ( $obj->sku == 5221 ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
echo 'After'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a handy [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method that can easily take care of this. Basically, what you're trying to do is say: if the current array does not match the one I want to remove, include it by returning `TRUE`:

```
$badSku = "5221";

$myNewArray = array_filter($myArray, function($currObject){
  return $currObject["sku"] != $badSku;
});
```

You could also do this manually with a traditional loop. Just make sure to start from the end to avoid pointer issues:

```
$badSku = "5221";

for($i = count($myArray); $i > 0; $i--) {
  if($myArray[$i]["sku"] == $badSku) {
    array_splice($myArray, $i, 1);

    // If you know there is only a single match, you can break here for optimal efficiency
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `unset()` function to delete the record from array...

```
<?php
$string = '[{"sku":"5221","qty":1,"price":17.5,"desc":"5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"},{"sku":"11004","qty":1,"price":30.95,"desc":"150 - Q-Plus 16oz"}]';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    if($val['sku']=='5221')
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

This will output :

Associative array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 11004
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 30.95
            [desc] => 150 - Q-Plus 16oz
        )

)
```

JSON array will be like this and deleted record sku = 5221

```
{"1":{"sku":"11004","qty":1,"price":30.95,"desc":"150 - Q-Plus 16oz"}}
```